# Proof of $(A \cap B) \cup (B \cap C) \cup (C \cap A) = (A \cup B) \cap (B \cup C) \cap (C \cup A)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Prove that

$(A \cap B) \cup (B \cap C) \cup (C \cap A) = (A \cup B) \cap (B \cup C) \cap (C \cup A)$

I have noted $\mathcal{A} = x \in A$, $\mathcal{B} = x \in B$, $\mathcal{C} = x \in C$

So in logical terms, the expression is:

$$(\mathcal{A} \land \mathcal{B}) \lor (\mathcal{B} \land \mathcal{C}) \lor (\mathcal{C} \land \mathcal{A})$$

By applying the distributive law two times, the closest I could get is:

$$\Big[(\mathcal{A} \land \mathcal{C}) \lor (\mathcal{A} \lor \mathcal{C})\Big] \land \Big[(\mathcal{B} \lor \mathcal{A}) \land (\mathcal{B} \lor \mathcal{C})\Big]$$

Could you give me some indications on how to properly prove this by working with formulas (not Venn Diagrams)?

Comment: Are you sure that is what you need to prove? Both sides of your equation are identical...

Comment: Draw a Venn diagram.

Comment: @Arthur I doubt Venn diagrams are accepted as proofs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seems to be in the right track. Indeed we just need to do some distributivity:

> **Distribuitivity of $\cup$:** $(X \cap Y) \cup Z = (X \cup Z) \cap (Y \cup Z)$
>
> **Distribuitivity of $\cap$:** $(X \cup Y) \cap Z = (X \cap Z) \cup (Y \cap Z)$

Then we start by the left hand side $(A \cap B) \cup (B \cap C) \cup (C \cap A)$ and move by $\cup$-distribution (from left to right) also distributing the inner $\cap$ eventually left from the $\cup$-distribution:

$(A \cap B) \cup (B \cap C) \cup (C \cap A) = $

$=(A \cup (B \cap C)) \cap (B \cup (B \cap C)) \cup (C \cap A)$

$= ((A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C)) \cap (B \cup (B \cap C)) \cup (C \cap A)$

$= ((A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C)) \cap ((B \cup B) \cap (B \cup C)) \cup (C \cap A)$

$= ((A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C) \cap (B \cup C)) \cup (C \cap A)$

And now we continue the process with one more $\cup$-distribution (and the other eventually inner distributions) until get the final statement we want.

Answer (score 1):

for $x \in (A \cap B) \cup (B \cap C) \cup (C \cap A) $ prove that $x \in (A \cup B) \cap (B \cup C) \cap (C \cup A)$

After that for $x \in (A \cup B) \cap (B \cup C) \cap (C \cup A)$
prove that $x \in (A \cap B) \cup (B \cap C) \cup (C \cap A)$.

**Another Method**

Use the property

$(A \cap B) \cup C=(A\cup C) \cap (A\cup C)$.
& $(A \cup B) \cap C=(A\cap C) \cup (A\cap C)$

Just use first $ (A \cap B) \cup (B \cap C)=(A\cup (B \cap C)) \cap (B \cup (B \cap C)) $
Now simplify more, then take $(A \cap B) \cup (B \cap C) \cup (C \cap A)$.

Next simplify $(A \cup B) \cap (B \cup C) \cap (C \cup A)$. Show bothof them are same.

Comment: I don't get what you mean with the first method, and I have used the two properties in the "another method" you have suggested, and I got stuck at the step I have mentioned in the question. Please enlighten me.

Comment: Actually when you have stated the Venn Diagram, I don't know whether you know the 1st process or not. Thats why I have mentioned the two methods. Take whatever is suitable for you.